# Java method with lower bounded(super) type

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters, wildcard

For example, I have next class, with bounded type parameter:

```
public class ItemContainer<T> {
    void addItems(List<T> items);
}
```

And usage in another class with parameter:

```
public class ItemsGenerator<T> {
    public void putItems() {
        ItemContainer<? super T> itemContainer = getItemContainer();
        List<? super T> items = getItems();
        itemContainer.addItems(items); // compilation error!
    }
}
```

From my understanding the problem is that it is unknown whether the first (ItemContainer) generic parameter would be the same as the second(List) or not. The good solution could be to define generic lower bound type to the method:

```
public <S super T> void putItems() {
    ItemContainer<S> itemContainer = getItemContainer();
    List<S> items = getItems();
    itemContainer.addItems(items); // ok
}
```

But, surprisingly (as for me), there is no such syntax(
[slightly unconvincing reason](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107))!
Is there any way to resolve this problem? I'm sure that (in my case) the first and the second parameter would be the same, but I don't know how to explain it to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Java doesn't allow this for the reason that two instances, though having same super, might not be of same class and hence avoiding runtime exceptions. Since you are sure that they will always be of same class, why not use same Type in itemContainer and items?

```
    ItemContainer<T> itemContainer = new ItemContainer<>();
    List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Because the generic type parameter of itemContainer and items should be the super type of  T (defined in the class header).

Comment: @DenisDorohov: "the super type of T" There is no "the" super type of `T`. `? super T` means it can be any type that is a supertype of `T`, including `T` itself, `T`'s direct superclass, that class's superclass, etc. (including any implemented interfaces, etc.) all the way to `Object`.